# SQL Group by using different conditions and multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have an Addresses Table, with columns being: **A,B,C,D......Address, Number, State, City, Zip****

I need to get a count of distinct addresses that can be grouped by 2 different conditions:

(Address, Number, State, City)
OR
(Address, Number, Zip)

The reason for the 2 conditions is that Zip can be null in some cases with City and State provided and vice versa.
**However, in cases where all 3 are present, the final table should just have 1 row for that address**

```
select State, City, Address, Number
into T1
from Main Table
group by State, City, Address, Number

select Zip, Address, Number
into T2
from Main Table
group by Zip, Address, Number

select a.*, b.Zip into JoinT1T2 from T1 a inner join T2 b 
on a.Address=b.Address AND a.Number=b.Number 

select count(*) from JoinT1T2
```

But this is not giving me the desired result.

Comment: Show us some sample data and expected results!

Comment: Do you need a "final table" satisfying some condition or do you need a count? Those are two different results.

Comment: @Fred I need the counts in the final table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new field called TypeOfDir, using the `CASE` instruction to get a value from 1 to 3 for the differents conditions that you have.
Then you can group by that new field.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. Only 2 conditions that we have.

Comment: You described three conditions: No Zip but City/State, No City/State but Zip, Both Zip and City/State.

Comment: Like Fred said, you have those three conditions.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is define the condition as an extra column. You don't need to add this to the table (although it will help performance), you can do this on the fly if you want, by using `CROSS APPLY`.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT HasZip, State, City, Zip, Address, Number
    FROM Table t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CASE WHEN Zip IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ) v(HasZip)
) t
```